Can I intercept schema creation in ef core?
Is there any way to intercept schema creation. I mean something like this.
I have db context registration like this:
Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options
     .UseSqlServer()
     .MyExtensionMethod())

This my extension method extends DbContextOptionsBuilder and I need to intercept OnModelCreating method from this method.
My goal is to when user calls this extension method, I will add another entity into this db context through ModelBuilder.Entity<> configuration.
This new entity is actually class in my library (this extension methods is also part of this library). So I want to intercept users schema creation from MyExtensionMethod and add new table into it. How can I do this?
I have tried using IModelCustomizer but the problem is that it needs to replace current implementation and I am afraid of using it because maybe user is using some custom customizer and with my extension method I will replace it. It will break users functionality.
Maybe it will be very helpful if somehow I will decorate current IModelCustomizer but when I tried it, I couldn't find any way of doing this

Yes, you can achieve this by replacing IModelCustomizer in the options.
Here’s a sample implementation for such an extension method:
public static class MyLibraryOptionsExtensions
{
    public static DbContextOptionsBuilder MyExtensionMethod(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IModelCustomizer, MyLibraryCustomModelCustomizer>();
        return optionsBuilder;
    }
}

public class MyLibraryCustomModelCustomizer : RelationalModelCustomizer
{
    public MyLibraryCustomModelCustomizer(ModelCustomizerDependencies dependencies) : base(dependencies)
    {
    }

    public override void Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
    {
        // Add your custom configurations here
        ApplyCustomConventions(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void ApplyCustomConventions(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // register any entities, which you want
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>();
    }
}


The problem that I see in this implementation is that, let's imagine I am using two libraries and both of them uses this method for creating database scheme for their usecases. both of them will use ReplaceService method and it means that one of them will be dropped. I mean something like this:
optionsBuilder
.ExtensionMethodFromLibrary1()
.ExtensionMethodFromLibrary2().
in this case ExtensinoMethodFromLibrary2() will replace Customizer of ExtensionMethodLibrary1.
can you suggest any solution for this problem?

@sindiofala, I thought about that from the start, but not found ideal solution (analysed EF Core source code). And probably I will not used such approach in Open Source library. I will create additional extension method over ModelBuilder and specified in documentation that it is required to execute in OnModelCreating.
